# Search from large set of input

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

help i need a fast query.

here is my case:

I have 2 tables, employees and periods.

let's say table employees contain emp_no,emp_name
table periods contain period_code, emp_no.

that looks fine until, user input 30k data and search them all.

my first idea is something like this

```
SELECT p.* from periods p
INNER JOIN employees e ON p.emp_no = e.emp_no
WHERE p.period_code = 'p01' and (e.emp_no IN (first 5k emp_no) or e.emp_no IN (another 5k emp_no), etc).
```

But from that query it wont return any employee that not in that period.
Let's say only 10k employee is in that period, another 10k is real data but those employee not in p01 and the other 10k is non exists data but user input and search it.

**i have another idea but not really sure about it**.
I create temporary table, and it will insert all emp_no that user search.
and then I join them so it will tell which employee is exists in period and in table employee, which employee not in that period and which emp_no that not valid.

somehting like

```
SELECT t.emp_no,ee.emp_name,p.pcode from employee e
JOIN period p ON p.emp_no = e.emp_no
RIGHT JOIN temp_t t ON t.emp_no = p.emp_no
LEFT JOIN employee ee ON ee.emp_no = t.emp_no
```

[image: result]

which the result is good, because only emp01 not null in pcode field

you guys have any better approach without inserting data into temp tables?

ps:i dont know why sqlfiddle not work, here some for test

```
CREATE TABLE employee
    (`emp_no` VARCHAR(7), `emp_name` varchar(7))
;
CREATE TABLE period
    (`pcode` VARCHAR(7), `emp_name` varchar(7))
;
CREATE TABLE temp_t
    (`emp_no` VARCHAR(7))
;

INSERT INTO employee
    (`emp_no`, `emp_name`)
VALUES
    ('emp01', 'name1'),
    ('emp02', 'name2')
;

INSERT INTO period
    (`pcode`, `emp_no`)
VALUES
    ('p01', 'emp01')
;

INSERT INTO temp_t
    (`emp_no`)
VALUES
    ('emp01'),
    ('emp02'),
    ('emp03')
;
```

Comment: please try explain you goal ... show a proper data sample and the expected  .. result  .. you question seems not clear to me ..

Comment: I, too, am unclear on what you are searching for.  You want list of all the employees _in_ a certain "period"?  Not in?  Something else?

Comment: i'm asking for better approach to list all searched employee whose in the period and whose not in period and which empno that not exists in db with just single query.

actually i already did. and how i did this?


thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, every table should have a `PRIMARY KEY`.  *Probably* `employee` should have `PRIMARY KEY(emp_no)` and `period` should have `PRIMARY KEY(pcode)`.

After that, please describe, in words, what you are trying to achieve.